# MapReduce Netsuite Error While Running SuiteScript

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite

Running into an issue that is driving me nuts does anyone have any idea what is wrong. Trying to do a map reduce of current S/O's in the NetSuite system calling a saved search.

Error
Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"missing ; before statement (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#73)","stack":[]}

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType MapReduceScript
@NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
 define(['N/record']), 
 function (record){

    function getInputData(inputContext) {
   try{
         
            var mySearch = record.load({
                id: 'customsearch_my_so_search'
            });
            mySearch.run().each (function(result) {
                var entity= result.getValue({
                    name: 'entity'
                });
                var subsidiary = result.getValue({
                    name: 'subsidiary'
                });
                return true;
            })
        }
        catch(e){
            log.debug('Error in GET INPUT DATA',e);
        };
    }

    function map (mapContext) {
        try{
            var searchResult = JSON.parse(mapContext.value);
            var salesOrderId = searchResult.id;
            var objRecord = recordId.load({
                fromType: recordId.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                fromId: salesOrderId,
                isDynamic: true,
                isClosed: true
            });
            
            var recordId = objRecord.save({
                enableSourcing: true,
                ignoreMandatoryFields: true
            });
            context.write({
                key : salesOrderId
            });
        }
        catch(e){
            log.error('Exception in MAP is', e);
        }
    }
    function summarize(summary) {
        try{
            var type = summary.toString();
            log.audit(type + 'Document Number' + summary.usage);
            log.audit(type + 'Internal ID' + summary.usage);
            log.audit(type + 'Status' + summary.usage);
            log.audit(type + 'Line Unique Key' + summary.usage);
            log.audit()
        }catch(e){
            log.error("Exception in SUMMARIZE",e);
        }
    }
   
   
    return {
        getInputData:getInputData,
        map:map, 
        summarize:summarize,
     
    }
});
```

Comment: You made some mistakes as you mentioned you trying to load a save search but you using record module function to load the save search.

Comment: I saw while going through your script you using `recordId.load` to load a record in `map entry point`, you need to change that too need to use `record.load`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your code.
use N/search module to load save search or create search within the script.

```
    /**
    *@NApiVersion 2.x
    *@NScriptType MapReduceScript
    @NModuleScope SameAccount
    */
     define(['N/record','N/search']), 
 function (record,search){

    function getInputData(inputContext) {
   try{
         
            var mySearch = search.load({
                id: 'save search id'
            });
            mySearch.run().each (function(result) {
                var entity= result.getValue({
                    name: 'entity'
                });
                var subsidiary = result.getValue({
                    name: 'subsidiary'
                });
                return true;
            })
        }
        catch(e){
            log.debug('Error in GET INPUT DATA',e);
        };
    }

    return {
        getInputData:getInputData
     
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.
Note - I have updated the getInputData entry point.